# Convert docx to PDF using spire.doc

Tags: c#, spire.doc

I need to convert word document to PDF. I am using spire.doc for the same purpose. Everything is working fine but one. I have a header section defined in Word Document which is missing in PDF after conversion. 
Can anyone help me how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: which version of spire doc are you using?

Comment: v5.5. This is the latest one I guess

Comment: Have you find a solution ?

Comment: Were you successful?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
Section section = document.Sections[0];
HeaderFooter header = section.HeadersFooters.Header;
Paragraph HParagraph = header.AddParagraph();
TextRange HText = HParagraph.AppendText("Spire.Doc for .NET");

//Set Header Text Format
HText.CharacterFormat.FontName = "Algerian";
HText.CharacterFormat.FontSize = 15;
HText.CharacterFormat.TextColor = Color.RoyalBlue;

//Set Header Paragraph Format
HParagraph.Format.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
HParagraph.Format.Borders.Bottom.BorderType=BorderStyle.ThickThinMediumGap;
HParagraph.Format.Borders.Bottom.Space = 0.05f;
HParagraph.Format.Borders.Bottom.Color = Color.DarkGray;
```

Instruction from [here](http://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/Spire.Doc/Spire.Doc-Program-Guide/NET-Word-Insert-Header/Footer-in-Word-Document.html)